# How html code flow works with internal CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm new in this world of HTML and CSS, so i just want to ask how the html code flow works, specifically html with internal CSS, so as i remember the code starts from the top to the bottom, giving this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta>.......
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .container {background-color: tomato; padding: 20px;}
      .text {color: green;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="text">Hello World!!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i would say that this runs normally, but what is first? i mean for example..  we can say that first the CSS styles are saved in a box then html elements are created and finally that box where the CSS rules are looks for the class names, tag names that are declared as CSS rules and starts matching and applying the styles with the correct html element that has relation with this ones (and resolving the complex stuff like specificity...)?, i mean that is how i think it works, in a nutshell am i correct??, and sorry if this sounds dumb i'm new in this :(

Comment: It's an involved process that's covered in many resources, like https://www.webperf.tips/tip/browser-rendering-pipeline/

Comment: All the code in the body tag run line by line and the associated CSS elements are then called to do their styling part. So, it all depends on which HTML tag appears first inside the body tag.

Comment: Check this article https://developer.chrome.com/articles/renderingng-architecture/

Comment: In a nutshell, yes, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css in three type

> inline css
> internal css
> external css

in internal css you write code

```
<style> write your css </style>
```

in inline css for example

```
<h1 style="background-clour:red;">Hello </h1>
```

in externel css you can call tag by name, id,and so on

the page must be connected to the html page in the top.

```
<link href="../dashboard-file/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is your answer.